# Use jQuery to set Focus on input before span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following bootstrap html:

```
<div class="input-group">                                                    
    <input id="dbTest" class="input-sm input-s datepicker-input form-control dirty" type="text" data-bind="datepicker:DOB" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" readonly="readonly">                                                   
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="dp3"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

The data-bind is a knockout extension which is all working well and when the focus is on the input all the datepicker works.  I created a test for this like so:

```
$("#dp3").click(function () {
   $("#dbTest").focus();
});
```

What I want to achieve though is the ability to create a global function for the addon button for any other datepickers I create so that I don't have to add ids and a function for every datepicker I create.  For example I would want to add say a class called datepicker-addon:

```
<span class="input-group-addon datepicker-addon" id="dp3"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
```

And then do something like:

```
$(".datepicker-addon").each(function() {
    $(relevant input).Focus();
});
```

Any ideas on how I could get the relevant input element?

Comment: how are you defining what the `relevant input` is? that is, in words, so we can help you write the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand, but given your markup if you are trying to focus on the input without id's etc you could use

```
$(".datepicker-addon").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('input').Focus();
})
```

N.B. as someone mentioned, you might of meant `click()` in your question rather then `each()`, in which case

```
$(".datepicker-addon").on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('input').Focus();
})
```

is what you'd want.

Comment: I just added to what the OP posted, certainly this code will only focus on the last element in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

if the span and input are next to each other I would use jquery .prev() function instead of parent then find.
http://api.jquery.com/prev/

```
$(".datepicker-addon").each(function() {
   $(this).prev().Focus();
})
```

.prev looks at the html elemnet immediatly before the current element.

.prev vs .parrent matters solely on your html structure.  Is the input always right before the datepicker?  Is there always only one input inside the parent element of the datepicker
The former would seem a much better constraint than the latter from an outsiders perspective.

Comment: prev() is def the better option if applicable

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input tag:

- always has class 'datepicker-input'
- always comes before span with addon button

you can use following code:

```
$('.input-group-addon').click(function(){
    $(this).prev('.datepicker-input').focus();
});
```